# Conflito cross-browser na largura da janela

Tags: css, navegador-de-internet

Estou a trabalhar num site, o problema é quando a janela tem menos de 500px, no Firefox a navbar (navBar.css) aparece de uma maneira (correta) e no Chrome aparece de outra. Como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude essa linha:

```
#missValMob, #namesJobsMob, #middleTextMob {
    display: inline-block; /* estava display: block; */
}
```

Isso deve ter acontecido uma vez que os dois navegadores apresentam diferenças na renderização, que, ainda que mínimas, geram alguns problemas.

Comment: Ou ainda algum atributo foi reconhecido pelo Chrome mudando a apresentação do `display` causando o problema. Tal atributo não foi reconhecido pelo Firefox. Não olhei o resto do código, busquei somente a falha, não posso confirmar.

Comment: Muito obrgado, resultou... Já pesquisei mas não comprrendi muito bem a diferença entre "block" e "inline-block", Achas que consegues explicar como se estivesses a falar com uma criança sff?

Comment: ELI5? OK, vou editar a resposta dando a explicação da diferença entre ambas, mas não sei se ela aplica ao caso. Deu certo mas foi por experiências anteriores, um chute.

Comment: Enquanto vou editando a resposta: seu site tem alguns elementos com `id` igual, recomendo arrumar isso. Esse atributo deve ser único por página.

Comment: Creio que tem id's iguais para os elementos com a mesma formatação

Comment: Já descobri afinal, bgado

Comment: Use `class`es nesse caso, classes você pode ter quantas quiser, enquanto `id`s são uma por página.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13516/discussion-between-miguel-and-gustavo-rodrigues)

Answer (score 0):

Aplique essas regras no seu css, acredito que ira funcionar conforme pretendido:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
#upBar {
    top: 0;
}
#wrapper > header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Não resultou, está na mesma... no chrome a navbar parece estar dependente da div "3 gerações...", não percebo porquê